# Можно ли повесить на родительский элемент addEventListener чтобы он сработал на дочерних элементах?

Tags: javascript, dom

Можно ли сделать, чтобы обработчик который повесил на общий родительский элемент, непосредственно реагировал на самый глубоко вложенный дочерний элемент? В данном случает это параграфы внутри дивов внутри дива?

```js
let items = document.getElementById('items');
let item = items.getElementsByTagName('P');

items.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target === item) {
    console.log('Клик по параграфу')
  }
})
```

```html
<div id='items'>
  <div class='item'>
    <p>Параграф 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Параграф 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Параграф 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вы один элемент сравниваете с массивом

Comment: для html/css/js рекомендую использовать *Фрагмент кода*, Вам необходимо реализовать корректное определение что произошел клик по нужному Вам элементу, вместо этого: `if (event.target === item){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе нужно делегирование по event.target, 
вот если коротко: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYu3KszRnB4 

Вот если не разбираться код который вам нужен:

```js
let items = document.getElementById('items');

items.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const  { target } = e;
    if (target.matches('p')) {
        console.log('Клик по параграфу')
    }
})
```

Вот если не понятно:

```js
let items = document.getElementById('items');

items.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === "P") {
        console.log('Клик по параграфу')
    }
})
```

Comment: я еще понимаю, кидать ссылки на печатные статьи или мануалы, но на видео-ролики. что за дичь?

Comment: Некоторые так могут лучше понять, я же не только на ролик ссылку дал.

Answer (score 1):

Вот таким образом можно реализовать.

```js
let items = document.getElementById('items');
let item = items.getElementsByTagName('P');

items.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'P') {
    console.log('Клик по параграфу:', event.target.textContent);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id='items'>
  <div class='item'>
    <p>Параграф 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Параграф 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Параграф 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```